# Почему когда я ввожу в Hour.Text цифру к примеру 1 мне пишет что 1 is an invalid integer?

Tags: pascal, lazarus

```
unit Unit1;

{$mode objfpc}{$H+}

interface

uses
  Classes, SysUtils, Forms, Controls, Graphics, Dialogs, StdCtrls, ExtCtrls,
  MaskEdit;

type

  { TForm1 }

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    MinLable: TLabel;
    HourLabel: TLabel;
    IntervalLabel: TLabel;
    Hour: TMaskEdit;
    Min: TMaskEdit;
    Interval: TMaskEdit;
    ResultButton: TButton;
    Result: TLabeledEdit;
    procedure HourChange(Sender: TObject);
    procedure IntervalChange(Sender: TObject);
    procedure MinChange(Sender: TObject);
    procedure ResultButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
  private

  public

  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  strthour, strtmin, intervalinmin, endhour, endmin:integer;

implementation

{$R *.lfm}

{ TForm1 }


procedure TForm1.HourChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if (StrToInt(Hour.Text) >= 0) and (StrToInt(Hour.Text) <= 23) then
     strthour:= StrToInt(Hour.Text);
end;

procedure TForm1.MinChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if (StrToInt(Min.Text) >= 0) and (StrToInt(Min.Text) <= 59) then
     strtmin:= StrToInt(Min.Text);
end;

procedure TForm1.IntervalChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
  intervalinmin:=StrToInt(Interval.Text)
end;


procedure TForm1.ResultButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  endmin:= strthour * 60 + strtmin + intervalinmin;
  endhour:= endmin div 60;
  endmin:= endmin mod 60;
  Result.Text:= IntToStr(endhour div 10) + IntToStr(endhour mod 10) + ':' + IntToStr(endmin div 10) + IntToStr(endmin mod 10);


end;

end.
```

```
procedure TForm1.HourChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if (StrToInt(Hour.Text) >= 0) and (StrToInt(Hour.Text) <= 23) then
     strthour:= StrToInt(Hour.Text);
end;
```

Почему когда я ввожу в Hour.Text цифру к примеру 1 мне пишет что 1 is an invalid integer  ? Это же целое число ?
Если что у меня MaskEdit и в шаблоне стоит ##

РЕШЕНИЕ:

```
unit Unit1;

{$mode objfpc}{$H+}

interface

uses
  Classes, SysUtils, Forms, Controls, Graphics, Dialogs, StdCtrls, ExtCtrls,
  MaskEdit, Spin;

type

  { TForm1 }

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    MinLab: TLabel;
    IntervalLab: TLabel;
    HourLab: TLabel;
    ResultButton: TButton;
    Result: TLabeledEdit;
    Hour: TSpinEdit;
    Min: TSpinEdit;
    Interval: TSpinEdit;
    procedure HourChange(Sender: TObject);
    procedure IntervalChange(Sender: TObject);
    procedure MinChange(Sender: TObject);
    procedure ResultButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
  private

  public

  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  nachhour, nachmin, intervalinmin, endhour, endmin:integer;

implementation

{$R *.lfm}

{ TForm1 }


procedure TForm1.HourChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TryStrToInt(Hour.Text, nachhour);
end;

procedure TForm1.MinChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TryStrToInt(Min.Text, nachmin);
end;


procedure TForm1.IntervalChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TryStrToInt(Interval.Text, intervalinmin);
end;



procedure TForm1.ResultButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  endmin:= nachhour * 60 + nachmin + intervalinmin;
  endhour:= endmin div 60;
  endmin:= endmin mod 60;
  Result.Text:= IntToStr(endhour div 10) + IntToStr(endhour mod 10) + ':' + IntToStr(endmin div 10) + IntToStr(endmin mod 10);
end;
end.
```

Comment: Запустите в отладчике и посмотрите, что именно у вас в `Hour.Text` оказывается

Comment: Кстати, на все ваши вопросы есть ответы, но ни один ответ не принят. Ознакомьтесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: @MBo я поставил некоторым галочку, но что делать если ответы не помогли ?

Comment: @Lucifer04 Конечно, бывает и так. Порой надо диалог вести, пока не разберешься. Но нередко и не получаешь правильного ответа. Просто если вообще  ни одного ответа не принято - может, человек не знает или не задумывается о принятии.

Comment: Раз уж Вы заменили `TMaskEdit` на `TSpinEdit`, то нет необходимости писать `TryStrToInt(Hour.Text, nachhour);`, поскольку у `TSpinEdit` есть целочисленное свойство `Value`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Если кратко, то причина в том, что при вызове `StrToInt()` содержимое `Hour.Text = '1 '` (содержит пробел). Соответственно, нужно или предварительно валидировать `Hour.Text`, или использовать функции `TryStrToInt()`/`StrToIntDef()`
2. Сомневаюсь, что маска `##` - это то, что Вам хотелось бы, т.к.

> #    only an optional number or + or -

Т.е. текст может содержать символы `+/-`. Скорее всего, более подходящей была бы маска `99`

> 9 only an optional number

3. Зачем Вы **трижды** используете `StrToInt()`? Достаточно единожды вызвать эту функцию, присвоив результат временной переменной.
4. Если уж требуются раздельные поля для часов и минут, то почему бы не использовать `TSpinEdit`? В его свойствах можно задать минимальное и максимальное значения, тем самым избежав лишних проверок.
5. На всякий случай. Поскольку речь о Lazarus, то в его наборе компонентов присутствует `TTimeEdit`

Comment: Я вот использовал TSpinEdit и задал мин = 0 макс = 24, но при вводе значения я могу туда вписать любое число к примеру 2345432, но хоть после нажатия Enter там будет 24 и вот вопрос можно ли сделать так что бы можно было ввести только 2-х значные числа ?

Comment: Skul Спасибо вам за ответ! Там в конце с выводом результата я оставил как было я просто не нашел TTimeEdit

Comment: `SpinEdit1.MaxLength := 2;`

Comment: а для чего это SpinEdit.1MaxLength :=2, я просто это в свойствах не нашел? Это должно решить проблему описанную на верху

Comment: `SpinEdit1.MaxLength := 2;` делает так, чтобы можно было ввести только 2-х значные числа.
Если Вам надо выполнять арифметические операции с датой-временем, подключите модуль `DateUtils` и воспользуйтесь стандартными функциями типа `IncHour()`, `IncMinute()` и т.п.

Comment: Спасибо за пояснение, а начальный 0 убрать можно что бы там изначально пусто было? И еще вы говорили что раз я использую TSpinEdit, то нет необходимости в переводе в int, но ```Hour.Text:= strthour;``` это выражение выводит ошибку мне придется перевести strthour в Str

Comment: У `TSpinEdit` есть целочисленное свойство `Value`. Оно доступно как для чтения, так и для записи. Сделать поле `TSpinEdit-a` изначально пустым без изощрений, думаю, не получится. Но, как я и говорил, в наборе компонентов на вкладке `Misc` присутствует компонент `TTimeEdit`, и в нём это можно сделать (в Lazarus 3.0).

Comment: Scull А не знаете как заполнить 2 строка 2 столбец в StringGrind ??

Comment: `StringGrid1.Cells[1, 1] := 'Text';`

Comment: Scull 

```procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin

    cells:=StringGrid1.Cells[2,2];
    if (StrToFloatDef(cells, 0) >= 0) and (StrToFloatDef(cells, 0) <= 59)then
  else
      ShowMessage('ГГ');
end;  
```
Код выполняется успешно, но когда я ввожу в столбец 2 и строку 2 к примеру = 234, моя ошибка не выводится. Может я не в то поле ввожу ? 
Я вообще могу вписывать в таблицу числа и делать с ними арифметические операции ?? 
И еще это тема для отдельного вопроса? Что бы если вы ответили вам баллы давали!

Comment: Нумерация строк и столбцов начинается с 0 (нуля), поэтому `Cells[2,2]` - это 3-я строка и 3-й столбец.
Если сравниваемое значение целочисленное, то лучше использовать `StrToIntDef` или `TryStrToInt`.
Преобразование лучше сделать один раз. Т.е. объявить `var cellValue: Integer;`, сделать преобразование `cellValue := StrToIntDef(cellValue, 0);` и затем уже сравнивать это значение.
В модуле `Math` есть функция `InRange`, можно записать условие как `if InRange(cellValue, 0, 59) then`. Мне кажется, это улучшит читаемость кода.
Можно плюсовать комментарии, но начисляют ли за это баллы - не знаю

Comment: Scull Ну мне просто нужно что бы пользователь вводил расходы и доходы за 12 месяцов (то есть тип должен быть flaot).  И дальше при нажатие на кнопку в" отдельном Edit вывести общую_сумму_расходов доходов и прибыль за год. Можете помочь вот тут я задал этот вопрос [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1562092/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%b2-lazarus]

Comment: @Ols Skull Здравствуйте! Я опять с вопросом, я хочу из кнопки сделать переключатель, который меняет у моих других кнопок их значение caption. Я хочу сделать что-то типа переключателя языка между RU И EN. И я вот не знаю как сделать для кнопки 2 значения. Есть кнчно ComboBox но ему нельзя задать Caption

Comment: @Lucifer04, Если нужно, чтобы была одна кнопка, выполняющая разные действия, то можно воспользоваться компонентом `ActionList`, создав в нём 2 отдельных `Action` (допустим, `Act1` и `Act2`). У каждой прописать нужный `Caption`. Изначально назначить `Act1` свойству `Action` у кнопки. В методе `OnExecute` для `Act1` прописать нужные действия и переназначить `Action` для кнопки на `Act2`. Для `Act2` провернуть противоположную замену. Но если в перспективе список языков расширится, то лучше поискать соответствующее готовое решение для локализации.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Можете помочь с этим [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1566606/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5-%d1%81-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%b2-lazarus]