# Как присвоить переменной для вычисления, значение вводимое в поле таблицы?

Tags: pascal, lazarus

Есть код программы которая считает **общую сумму доходов расходов и прибыль за год**:

```
var 
  Dohodi:array [1..12] of real; 
  Rashodi:array [1..12] of real; 
  Month:integer; 
  PribilJanDec, ObshayaSummaDohodov, ObshayaSummaRashodov, Pribil:real; 
begin 
  writeln('|Введите кол-во доходов за Январь-Декабрь|'); 
  for Month:= 1 to 12 do 
  begin 
    write(Month,' месяц: '); 
    read(Dohodi[Month]); 
  end; 
  
    writeln('|Введите кол-во расходов за Январь-Декабрь|'); 
  for Month:= 1 to 12 do 
  begin 
    write(Month,' месяц: '); 
    read(Rashodi[Month]); 
  end; 
  
  PribilJanDec:= 0; ObshayaSummaDohodov:= 0; ObshayaSummaRashodov:= 0; Pribil:= 0; 
  
  for Month:= 1 to 12 do 
    begin 
      PribilJanDec:= PribilJanDec + Dohodi[Month]; 
      ObshayaSummaDohodov:= ObshayaSummaDohodov + Dohodi[Month]; 
      ObshayaSummaRashodov:= ObshayaSummaRashodov + Rashodi[Month]; 
      Pribil:= Pribil + (Dohodi[Month] - Rashodi[Month]); 
    end; 
  
  
  writeln('Прибыль: ', PribilJanDec:0:2); 
  writeln('Общая сумма доходов: ', ObshayaSummaDohodov:0:2); 
  writeln('Общая сумма расходов: ', ObshayaSummaRashodov:0:2); 
  writeln('Прибыль за год: ', Pribil:0:2); 
  
  
  readln; 
  readln; 
end.
```

Это *^консольная версия^*

Мне нужно сделать ее в графической версии, я хотел сделать это через таблицу использовав компонент TStringEdit.
Вот тут я немного сделал:

```
unit Unit1;
{$mode objfpc}{$H+}
interface
uses  Classes, SysUtils, Forms, Controls, Graphics, Dialogs, Grids, ValEdit, Math;
type
  { TForm1 }
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    StringGrid1: TStringGrid;    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure StringGrid1EditingDone(Sender: TObject);  private
  public
  end;
var
  Form1: TForm1;
  realValue: Real;
  valueFromGrid: String;
implementation
{$R *.lfm}
{ TForm1 }
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
end;
procedure TForm1.StringGrid1EditingDone(Sender: TObject);
begin  valueFromGrid := StringGrid1.Cells[1, 1];
  if valueFromGrid <> '' then
    begin         if TryStrToFloat(valueFromGrid, realValue) then
           ShowMessage('Cool')         else
           StringGrid1.Cells[1,1]:= '';    end;
end;

end.
```

Можете сказать как это сделать в таблице т.е как мне присвоить переменной для вычисления, значение вводимое в поле таблицы, то что я сделал так верно ?

фотография таблицы [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**РЕШЕНИЕ:**

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  pribil:= 0;
  for Month:= 1 to 12 do
       begin
        Dohodi:= StrToFloat(StringGrid1.Cells[Month, 1]);
        Rashodi:= StrToFloat(StringGrid1.Cells[Month, 2]);
        pribil:= Dohodi-Rashodi;
        StringGrid1.Cells[Month, 3]:= FloatToStr(pribil);
        obshiydoh+= Dohodi;
        ObshDoh.Text:= FloatToStr(obshiydoh);
        obshiyrash+=Rashodi;
        ObshRash.Text:= FloatToStr(obshiyrash);
        pribyear+= (Dohodi-Rashodi);
        PribilYr.Text:= FloatToStr(pribyear);
       end;

end;
end.
```

Comment: 1. В консольной программе `PribilJanDec` и `ObshayaSummaDohodov` - одинаковы, а `Pribil` можно посчитать вне цикла как `ObshayaSummaDohodov - ObshayaSummaRashodov`. Вроде бы.
2. Считать - так же, как и в консольной версии, с помощью цикла. Только создадите переменные `Dohod/Rashod` и будете в цикле им присваивать значения из грида: `Dohod := StrToFloat(Grid.Cells[0, Month]); Rashod := StrToFloat(Grid.Cells[1, Month]);` (в зависимости от того, с какого индекса данные начинаются).
3. Для фин. расчётов существует тип `Currency` и соответствующие функции типа `StrToCurr`, `FormatCurr` и т.п.

Comment: @OldSkull а в это цикл писать где в какой процедуре внутри form ?

Comment: @OldSkull 
```procedure TForm1.StringGrid1EditingDone(Sender: TObject);
begin
      for Month:= 1 to 12 do
       begin
        Dohodi:= StrToFloat(StringGrid1.Cells[0, Month]);
        Rashodi:= StrToFloat(StringGrid1.Cells[1, Month]);
       end;
end;
```

Comment: Кнопку киньте на форму, а в её обработчик поместите все расчёты. Когда заполните таблицу, нажмёте на эту кнопку.

Comment: 1. Первый параметр свойства `Cells` - это столбец. Т.е. `Cells[2, Month]` - это третий столбец, и Month-ая строка. Наберите в редакторе `StringGrid1.` и после точки нажмите Ctrl+Space - увидите все свойства/методы и их сигнатуры. 2. Я предполагал, что Вы все числа сами введёте в таблицу, а затем нажмёте кнопку и результат вычислится. 3. `Прибыль` - это не столбец, а строка. 4. В цикле после получения значений из ячеек нужно производить вычисления, как в консольной программе. Т.е. вся разница только в том, что в консольке текущие значения берутся из массива, а здесь - из грида

Comment: @OldSkull ```procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);

begin
  for Month:= 1 to 12 do
       begin
        Dohodi:= StrToFloat(StringGrid1.Cells[Month, 1]);
        Rashodi:= StrToFloat(StringGrid1.Cells[Month, 2]);
        pribil:= pribil + (Dohodi-Rashodi);
        StringGrid1.Cells[Month, 3]:= FloatToStr(pribil);

       end;


end;```

почему только первое значение прибыли правильное, а остальные неправильные

Comment: Потому что `pribil` - это суммарное значение, а Вам, насколько я понимаю, в грид нужно заносить разницу между текущими значениями. Т.е. должно быть `StringGrid1.Cells[Month, 3]:= FloatToStr(Dohodi-Rashodi);`, полагаю

Comment: @OldSkull Спасибо, я тоже вот только что сделал pribil:= (Dohodi-Rashodi) и все получилось

Comment: @OldSkull Как можно вывести ошибку, если в поле ввели символ, а потом этот символ стирается ? Я дополнил вопрос решенным кодом

Comment: 1. Не совсем понял вопрос. Но у грида много событий, например `OnKeyPress`, `OnValidateEntry` и т.п. Можно при каждом нажатии клавиш что-то проверять.
2. Думаю, в Вашем решении имеет смысл общий доход и расход отображать после завершения цикла, а вместо `pribyear+= (Dohodi-Rashodi);` написать `pribyear+= pribil;`